# PPTP + Ubuntu + Windows XP: Cant ping Router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-xp, vpn, pptp

I have an ubuntu server with 2 network cards: eth0, with a samba server and eth1 bridged to a Virtual Box Machine running windows xp.

When I connect to the network using VPN from another winxp computer, i can ping and access my samba sharings but I cant ping my router's ip (10.1.1.1) or the winxp machine inside virtual box. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox has issues with GREs across its NAT - it doesn't work. I haven't checked the latest versions, but I have not heard that has changed at this point.